# Text to the center or top right of an image and continue to align the text this way

Tags: html, css

So I know this has been asked, I want my text aligned to the top or center right of my image, however, in all examples a one liner works just fine, but when I add additional lines, they jump to the bottom or under the images. Here is my example

```
*img style="vertical-align:middle"src="/images/Logo/Eutopian-Trader-Favicon-E-200-??
200.jpg" width="75px" alt="Welcome To Eutopian Trader"> *span style="">At Eutopian Trader we pride ourselves with providing you an >>  unparrelled Customer Experience. ensuring we have the products you want, and >> the Customer Serivce you expect.
```

*/
When the text renders, only they very first line aligns properly and the rest of the text moves down under the image. I am basically looking for something that would look like this (where XXX is the image)

```
XXXX
XXXX  I want my text to stay up here
XXXX  and when it wraps or a new line
XXXX  I want the text to stay here
and then move under the image, but with the examples above this happens to me


XXXX
XXXX The text starts here but when it line wraps
XXXX
XXXX
or a new line, it moves down here. and this just
looks terrible. The code above is taken from 
the thread that explains how to get the text
to start where I want it but I can't find any
examples to make it look like the above example.
```

Sorry but I still have not figured out how to use this site properly 
to place the code correctly. I apologize in advance but Im trying and I can't figure it out so I used a * inplace of the <> in the tags.

Comment: Use the [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to show your code

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to like this

```css
.float-left{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="float-left"> The text starts here but when it line wraps or a new line, it moves down here. and this just
looks terrible. The code above is taken from 
the thread that explains how to get the text
to start where I want it but I can't find any
examples to make it look like the above example.</p>
```

Comment: Yes, that last one is exactly what I was looking for! thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you :).. Could you accept the answer if it solved your issue?